# Page.render() returns false

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, remotewebdriver

I'm using phantomjs for taking screenshots of several webpages. To get a screenshot image i have used the following code.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
page.viewportSize = { width: 1200,height: 800};
page.open('http://<randomwebpageAddress>', function(status) {
  console.log(status);
  console.log(page.render('screenshot.png'));
  phantom.exit();
});
```

but the result for some page is

`status = "success"` but page.render returns false

my question is:

when does `page.render()` return false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the documentation says that there is no return type for render(), it always returns a boolean denoting the success of the rendering operation.

The function will always return `false` if the [content is empty](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/2.0.0/src/webpage.cpp#L894), which should never happen.

Since the `render()` function is capable of rendering into multiple formats such as PNG, JPG, GIF, PDF, the return value may have slightly different meanings.

**PDF**

[`false` can only be returned](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/2.0.0/src/webpage.cpp#L1162), if the format options where set incorrectly.

**GIF (pre v2)**

It only [returns `false`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/1.9.8/src/gif/gifwriter.cpp#L48) when the destination file is not writable.

**JPG, PNG (and GIF)**

The return value [comes from](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/2.0.0/src/webpage.cpp#L940) `QImage::save()` and denotes a [successful rendering and file write](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/2.0.0/src/qt/qtbase/src/gui/image/qimage.cpp#L3147-L3148).

Comment: The reason for my failing of render() is URL redirect happens at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html), the return value of `render()` is not important.